# !file.eof() что происходит на последней итерации?

Tags: c++

Доброго вечера. 
Подскажите, почему данный код:

```
while (!file.eof())
{

    file >> p1.x >> p1.y;
    MyVector.push_back(p1);

    cout << p1.x << " " << p1.y<<endl;

}
```

При такой информации в файле:

```
0 0
0 10
10 10
10 0
```

Выведет следующее:

```
0 0 
0 10
10 10
10 0
10 0
```

и соответственно размер вектора будет равен 5?

P.S. надо обойти этот момент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не делайте так: `while (!file.eof())`

Эта проверка сработает только **после** **неудачного** чтения за концом файла.

А вы здесь

```
file >> p1.x >> p1.y;
MyVector.push_back(p1);
```

удачность чтения не проверяете...

Ну, раз @ixSci настаивает... [Менторским тоном] - надо вот так:

```
while (file >> p1.x >> p1.y)
{
    MyVector.push_back(p1);
    cout << p1.x << " " << p1.y<<endl;
}
```

Comment: @ Harry, удачность чтения проверяется выше в коде. В том числе и наличие файла используя `#include <experimental/filesystem>` и `!is_regular_file(filename)`

Comment: Так Вы покажите человеку как правильно, что же только проблему описали?

Comment: Ну, если вы все знаете и понимаете - зачем спрашивать?

Comment: @ixSci Человек, как видите, упирается ногами и руками... И потом - я фактически написал - **проверять удачность чтения** - этого мало?

Comment: Он просто не понимает, вряд ли упирается.